# Sparks observed when electrical outlet is turned off

Tags: electrical

I have engaged an electrician to rewire my electrical cables and outlets. I observed that when I switch off my electrical appliances, there is some sparks coming out.

Is this behaviour normal? Did the electrician make an mistake?

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Where are the sparks coming from?

Comment: I didnt notice there were any sparks before the change of cables/electrical outlets. It seems that the spark were within the outlet.

Comment: To clarify, are you seeing sparks in the receptacle when you flip a switch off on your appliance or on the wall, or when you pull the plug from the wall?

Comment: I am seeing sparks, when I flipped the switch off. The plug remains on the outlet.

Comment: Where on this planet are you anyway?

Comment: Does the "spark" stay contained within the switch? Can you see it if the switch was in direct sunlight, or only with the switch in a dimly lit area? When you open an electrical contact, it's common to get an arc. The size of the arc is dependent on the amount of current flowing, and the speed at which the contact opens.